# Matlab custom fitting fails

Tags: matlab, data-fitting

I have a bunch of data that I have to fit with the following formula: `[x*sin(1/x)]^2`. I don't really know what coefficients to pick for such a function, I tried:

```
model = fittype('a*((xx/b)*sin(b/xx))^2+c','independent',{'xx'},'dependent',{'FF_norm(:,i)'}, 'coefficients', {'a','b','c'});
opt=fitoptions(model);
myfit=fit(xx,FF_norm(:,i),model, opt);
myfit
plot(myfit,xx,FF_norm(:,i))
```

I always get a fit that looks just like a straight line. I know it's probably better to enter start points as well, but I have no idea how to pick these because I don't know how Matlab interprets them and so what they actually mean. When I try some numbers, it's always giving me errors.

Comment: What error it gives you when you try to use numbers?

Comment: I tried it again, and now I don't get any errors, but the fit is just ridiculous. The data actually look like a parabola and the fit is (or looks like) a straight horizontal line. No matter what start points I take, it stay a straight line. Is there maybe another way to do this? I tried the least square fitting, but also without any success.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what is the problem you encounter, but I tried to reproduce your problem with this code:

```
xx = (0.1:0.1:10).';
error = rand(size(xx)).*2;
data = 5.*((xx./6).*sin(6./xx)).^2+7+error;
model = fittype('a.*((xx./b)*sin(b./xx)).^2+c','independent',{'xx'},'dependent'...
    ,{'data'}, 'coefficients', {'a','b','c'});
opt = fitoptions(model);
opt.StartPoint = [1 1 1];
[myfit,gof] = fit(xx,data,model,opt)
plot(myfit,xx,data);
```

and it gave me this output:

```
myfit = 
     General model:
     myfit(xx) = a.*((xx./b)*sin(b./xx)).^2+c
     Coefficients (with 95% confidence bounds):
       a =        5.18  (4.846, 5.514)
       b =       6.318  (5.84, 6.796)
       c =       7.995  (7.777, 8.213)
```

which is quite correct, and also the plot looks fine:
[image: fitting model]

Indeed, it not always works on the first try, but you should try several times, until you get something fine. My way is using a `while` loop and the `gof` (goodness of fit) output from the `fit` function, to search for adequate parameters for the model. For the result above:

```
gof = 
           sse: 27.757
       rsquare: 0.91357
           dfe: 97
    adjrsquare: 0.91178
          rmse: 0.53493
```

This off course depend on how much data you have, but that fact is always true.

Comment: The problem is that the fit doesn't even come near the trend of the datapoints. I would show you the plot that I get but I don't know how to include figures here.. The values for the coefficients a, b and c should be somewhere around 1, 2*10^(-7) and 0 respectively. But these are the results that I get:

myfit = 

     General model:
     myfit(xx) = a.*((xx./b)*sin(b./xx)).^2+c
     Coefficients (with 95% confidence bounds):
       a =      0.8531  (-1.863e+06, 1.863e+06)
       b =   2.793e-08  (-0.0241, 0.0241)
       c =     -0.1468  (-1.863e+06, 1.863e+06)

Comment: @Apollo I don't need to see the plot, I need some sense of the data, can you give some example of it?